# Total sum of 4 different values Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, sum

I am trying to calculate the sum of 4 different values, they are all calculated using their data tags in the dom, however I have no idea how to fetch the total value of the four of them combined, here's my function.

```
    function calculateUserPricing(initialValues: boolean) {
    var displayElements = ["jsSuperUser", "jsUser", "jsResourceUser", "jsRessource"];
    for (var i in displayElements) {
        var element = $("div." + displayElements[i]);
        var quantity = parseFloat(element.data("price"));
        var users;
        var total;
        if (initialValues) 
            users = parseInt(element.data("users"));
        else 
            element.find(".jsDisplayPrice").text(currencySymbol + " " + $.formatNumber(quantity * users, lineCurrencyFormat));  
    }     
        for (var i in displayElements) {
            total += $(displayElements[i]);
            element.find(".jsDisplayTotal").text(currencySymbol + " " + $.formatNumber(total, lineCurrencyFormat));        
    }
}
```

The last bit is my attempt at fetching the value, however to no avail..

Here's the html, each element that shows its own total value looks like this, there's 4 of these boxes, and i need their grandsum It's the one classed as "jsDisplayTotal" that displays the individual boxes local total, they all look like this:

```
        <div class="container jsRessource" int:title="Ressource" data-price="{../@resource-sys}"
            data-users="{@resources}">
            <div class="box boxSmTxt">
                <xsl:text><int:text>Ressource</int:text></xsl:text>
            </div>
            <div class="boxLgTxt">
                <xsl:value-of select="@resources" />
            </div>
            <span class="prMnd">
                <xsl:value-of select="../@resource"></xsl:value-of>
                <xsl:text> <int:text>/ måned</int:text></xsl:text>
            </span>
            <div class="priceBox">
                <span class="price">
                    <span class="prMnd">
                        <span class="jsDisplayPrice" id="resourcePrice">
                        </span>
                        <xsl:text> <int:text>i alt</int:text></xsl:text>
                        <br/>                       
                        <xsl:text><int:text>Totalsum:</int:text> </xsl:text>
                        <span class="jsDisplayTotal"></span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**EDIT:** it's worth noting that the four values (prices) are stored in each their ".jsDisplayPrice" div which displays the total of that specific price category, however all these four prices must be added together to an grand total.

**EDIT2:** Tried something, but it doesn't work, just prints out 0, any feedback would be appreciated, code example below:

```
 var totalElement = $('.jsDisplayTotal');
    function calculateTotal() {
        var total = 0;
        $('.jsDisplayPrice').each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        totalElement.text(currencySymbol + " " + $.formatNumber(total, lineCurrencyFormat));
    }
    calculateTotal();
```

Structural sample of how it works:
[image: Structural sample]

This is 1 of the 4 user categories of which I am trying to combine the total of for a grandsum

The first big number is the quantity of users, the number "19" just below is a static number, what each user of this category will cost, the next line is the current total price of this specific category with the price * quantity, and this is the jsDisplayPrice .div the last line should be the totalsum of this particular category, and 3 more combined, the grandsum of all 4 user categories.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the structure with these 4 prices in it?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML/XML structure with the 4 prices in it...?

Comment: I editted the mid section with the entire html xsl markup for the picture you see below, there's 4 of these boxes, and they each have their own jsDisplayPrice (total) shown inside of them, however I want the grandsum of all 4 of these boxes, make sense?

Comment: I don't see any of the numbers in the HTML you provided. Is it not possible to give sample data and desired outcome (in text format)?

Comment: @trincot The numbers are being fetched from the `data-types` such as `data-users="{@resources}` and `data-price="{../@resource-sys}"` I really don't think it's that complicated, but for the life of me I can't get anything I try to work, sadly I can't just fill in static numbers in the html since it has to be dynamic and unique for each user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem I had by changing the existiting `calculateUserPricing()` function

like so:

```
function calculateUserPricing(initialValues: boolean) {
    var displayElements = ["jsSuperUser", "jsUser", "jsResourceUser", "jsRessource"];
    var total = 0;
    for (var i in displayElements) {
        var element = $("div." + displayElements[i]);
        var quantity = parseFloat(element.data("price"));
        var users;
        if (initialValues)
            users = parseInt(element.data("users"));
        else
            users = $(".entries tr.jsSuperUsers").length;
        var subtotal = quantity * users;
        total = total + subtotal;
        element.find(".jsDisplayPrice").text(currencySymbol + " " + $.formatNumber(subtotal, lineCurrencyFormat));
    }
    element.find(".jsDisplayTotal").text(currencySymbol + " " + $.formatNumber(total, lineCurrencyFormat));
}
```

It was easier and simpler to incorporate it in the existing function, since the value of the `calculateUserPricing` function was already formatted it didn't recognize it as a valid number

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var total = 0;
for (var i in displayElements) {
    var element = $("div." + displayElements[i]);
    var quantity = parseFloat(element.data("price"));
    var users;
    total += quantity;
}
element.find(".jsDisplayTotal").text(currencySymbol + " " + $.formatNumber(total, lineCurrencyFormat));
```

Comment: Hello jcubic, that returns the price we already know and print, but multiplied by whatever amount of users that (quantity) that category of the 4 values has, i want the four values' totals summed up to a grand total, jsDisplayPrice = values' totals,  there's 4 of them, jsDisplayTotal = grand total. :-)